# TypeError: r.teams is undefined - Codeigniter + jQuery Ajax + Aropupu Bracket library

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, typeerror

I'm using a ajax call in jQuery to get a variable from the server side to use in the jQuery Bracket library (http://www.aropupu.fi/bracket/) but the plugin doesn't recognizes the response from de server. If i use the result directly in jquery this works fine.

The server side:

```
function sortear_atletas() {
        $competicao_id = $this->input->post('competicao_id');
        //Example
        $atletas = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q");

        if (!empty($competicao_id)) {
            $atletasx = null;

            $team = $this->sorteios->sortear_grelha($atletas);
            $atletasx.= '{"teams": [';
            foreach ($team as $key => $value) {
                $atletasx.= '["' . $value[0] . '","' . $value[1] . '"],';
            }
            $atletasx.= ']}';

            echo $atletasx;

        }
    }
```

The client side:

```
$("#gerar_grelha_inscritos_btn").on("click", function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "competicoes/grelha_competicao/sortear_atletas",
                        data: {competicao_id: competicao_id},
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (response) {
                            $('#minimal').bracket({
                                init: response
                            });

                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.Error);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

The view:

```
<div id="minimal" class="demo"></div>
```

The error:

TypeError: r.teams is undefined

Comment: How can i convert the string from server to jQuery array for the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax request you donot specify the response type, like json,xml etc. Similarly on server side you echo a string. Whereas this plugin require array.

Comment: How can i convert the string from server to jQuery array for the plugin?

Comment: $atletasx= array();
            foreach ($team as $key => $value) {
                $atletasx[ ]= $value;
            }
           echo json_encode($atletasx);     In this case you will be returned a json which carry an array.

Comment: After do that i made this in client side: var atletas = {"teams": response};
                            $('#minimal').bracket({
                                init: atletas
                            }); and the erro is: TypeError: b.round(...).match(...) is undefined

Comment: Try debugging the error in console to know exactly what is being passed in "b". It seems   empty.

Comment: I think the problem is convert json objects array from server to client jQuery array. I don't know how do this. alert( var atletas = {"teams": response};) return [object Object].

Comment: Try passing response directly to init. And to log response you can use JSON.stringify(response).

Comment: I am missing it: header('Content-Type: application/json'); in the server side. Thanks  KnightIn.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using in the server side:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($atletasx);
```

and in the client side:

```
$("#gerar_grelha_inscritos_btn").on("click", function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "competicoes/grelha_competicao/sortear_atletas",
                        data: {competicao_id: competicao_id},
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        datatype: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert(response);
                            var atletas = response;
                            alert(atletas);
                            $('#minimal').bracket({
                                init: {"teams": atletas}
                            });

                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.Error);
                        }
                    });
                });
```